# Totally blank edit revision?

Tags: bug, revision-history

The OP apparently performed an edit (a one character add from the revision comment). Except:

[image: no change revision]

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/287756/revisions

So what was the change? Even an invisible character should appear in the markdown diff. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Servy Of course, and its going that way (hence the screenshot). Still would like to know if there is a bug in the system creating incorrect edit revisions though.

Comment: Perhaps the one character was removed again within the five minute grace period.

Comment: @NisseEngström I believe in such cases the revision history entry is supposed to go away (you can use that trick to reverse a vote as well)

Comment: @NisseEngström If someone did that it would [look like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/287760/revisions).  That's not what the linked revision looks like.

Answer (score 37):

The difference is in a single carriage return character. To test, I downloaded both revisions using the `source` link and diffed them in a hex editor.

[image: diff hex]

Ignoring the differences in the GUID in the `title` tag in the header, we can see that in revision 5 `79 0A 0D 0A` became `79 0D 0A 0D 0A`. This white space appears between the following two line in [the revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/287756/5).

> Thing is every one know some thing about answer. Soo you must post your answer very creativly but must answer corectly
>
> So when questioner thought your answer is best he will vote you.

Using Tamper Data, I was able to reproduce this with the [revision history to this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/287854/revisions) in revision 2.

Comment: I was about to suggest that it was a CR/LF issue, but I wouldn't have done such a nice investigation to prove that, as you did. Btw, reproducing that again in this post would be awesome! +1

Comment: @falsarella I just did it with this answer, see revision 2.

Comment: How the heck do you add a single carriage return? Thats a weird thing to do... Good catch though! Still weird that the markdown diff didn't catch it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Wööt? O.o' Well done! In fact, I don't think that's what happened in OP's case... Probably he posted the answer on Linux/Mac, edited on Windows, and then tried to manually rollback at Linux/Mac, but accidentally changed one CR/LF to an CR or an LF, depending on the environments used. Anyone interested in reproducing with these steps?

Comment: @falsarella: Except that linefeeds are usually normalized on the web (by your browser). If they're not using an external editor that directly talks to the SO API :-)

Comment: Hah, that's cool! I wonder if the markdown diff missing this qualifies as a bug or a feature...

Comment: What hex editor is that?

Comment: @eggyal That would be [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/), specifically [the latest release on GitHub](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/HexFiend/releases).