# Blank Revision in Revision History with no Diff Tool buttons

Tags: bug, revision-history, diff

I was looking at the revision history of [2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352386/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire) and came across  a strange revision.

If you look at the [list of revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/352386/revisions), the 8th revision appears blank. Not only that, the diff tool buttons do not appear.

> [image: blank revision]

If you go to [the page of just that revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/352386/8), you can see the question text, yet again, there are no diff tool buttons:

> [image: no diff tool]

I know in the past there have been reports of [revisions with 1 invisible return character](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287760/totally-blank-edit-revision), yet this seems to be a different problem, since in those cases, the diff tool buttons still appear.

Was something really changed in this revision? If yes, why is the change not displaying? If no, how was this revision submitted and why is it showing in the list of revisions?

Comment: Looks like revision 7 and 8 did the same thing so you see the change in 7 but you also see that zondo did something.  do concurrency it hard right is well to.

Comment: Odds are that while they were writing the edit someone else made the exact same edit before they could finish.

Comment: Looks like that might be what happened here. The revisions are listed as 2 minutes apart though, so I would think that is enough time to prevent concurrency issues. When the second person pressed the "Save Edits" buttons, the system should have checked then if there were any new changes, and blocked the edit if there were none.